# Linear groups $\mathrm{PSL}_n(F)$ and $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it true that "There is a part of $\mathrm{GL}_n(F)$ which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PSL}_n(F)$, $n \geq 4$"? So since $\mathrm{PSL}_n(F)$ is not solvable (it is simple non-abelian group), the former linear group is simply not solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\operatorname{GL}_n$ were solvable, then its subgroup $\operatorname{SL}_n$ would be solvable, and in turn the quotient $\operatorname{PSL}_n$ of the latter would also be solvable.

I doubt $\operatorname{GL}_n$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\operatorname{PSL}_n$.

**Later:** In that book, in exercise 324 on page 123 *sections* are defined as quotients of subgroups (I would say subquotients) so the translation done in the body of this question is wrong.

Comment: The first statement is exactly true. But there is a problem in " A Course on Group Theory by J.S.Rose" telling:

Comment: p 148: Let n is an integer, n>1, and F a field. since the group GL_n(F) has a section isomorphic to PSL_n(F), when n>2 then the former group is not solvable. I am thinking about the section mentioned there.

Comment: A section is a quotient of a subgroup, as in a quotient of SL_n(F).